# OpenVPN port forwarding without router forwarding?

Tags: openvpn, port-forwarding

I would like to setup an OpenVPN server with port forwarding on my VPS, because I can not forward ports in my home router.

The general question is, if it is even possible to bypass router port forwarding with a VPN connection?

Comment: Can you add a simple description of the network layout and what you are intending to do? What prevents you from forwarding ports on the router directly?

Comment: Notebook => Router => VPN1 => VPN2. Now i would like to forward a Port from VPN2 to my Notebook, **without** forwarding them on Router or VPN1. The question was, is this even possible?

Comment: Could you explain what is VPN1 & VPN2. Where is openvpn client and server?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you want to create a VPN from your notebook to a server somewhere "out there", and forward a port from the server to the notebook. That should be possible, provided the routing in the VPN is set up correctly, namely the server being able to reach the notebook. Any router restrictions are removed by using the VPN, which encapsulates any data flowing through it.

You can also achieve this with the port forwarding facility in SSH:

```
ssh -R port-srv:localhost:port-ntb user@srv
```

This instructs the `ssh` client to connect to server `srv` as user `user`, listen there on port `port-srv` and forward all incoming traffic to the port `port-ntb` on localhost (from the `ssh` client's point of view), which is the notebook. You can also forward the traffic to a third computer by replacing `localhost` with something else.