# SSH Connection into LAN without port forwarding?

Tags: ssh, sftp, port-forwarding

I'm living inside a study union for the next few month. the organisation has its own network and gateways where the students are connected to the internet.
problem: I don't have access to the routers but want to install my sftp-server.
is there a possibility to access from outside the LAN to my server via sftp?

Comment: See [How does reverse SSH tunneling work?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work), [How can I configure a reverse SSH connection to the connecting computer?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17835/how-can-i-configure-a-reverse-ssh-connection-to-the-connecting-computer), [SFTP over reverse SSH tunnel?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82582/sftp-over-reverse-ssh-tunnel)

Comment: Are you actually behind a NAT gateway?  I think most are assuming you are and that is why you are asking the question, but you don't say that.  Answer is much easier and very different if you aren't behind a NAT gateway.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you tunnel it from the inside to a server you can access from the internet first. You have to forward a port on a remote, publicly accessible machine to the port on your computer on which the `sftp-server` is listening. Basically you need to run on your server something like:

```
ssh -R public_port:localhost:internal_sftp_port public.server
```

See `ssh(1)` man page and also [OpenVPN port forwarding without router forwarding?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92651/openvpn-port-forwarding-without-router-forwarding)